# How to create a file API in Next.js using the app method API with Multer?

Tags: typescript, multer, filepond, next.js13

I’m trying to create an API for handling files, specifically pictures, in Next.js using the app method API and Multer. I’m not sure how to set it up correctly.

I want to be able to save an image in my Next.js app. However, I’m not sure how to set it up correctly.